# java.lang.NumberFormatException: ForInputString"7110332507339" java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT Parameter at Index::4

Tags: java, database, oracle, netbeans

[image]i am getting the below Exceptions

1)java.lang.NumberFormatException: ForInputString"7110332507339"

2)java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT Parameter at Index::4

even i am giving the correct data at the time of input. i have searched a lot to resolve this but still getting the exception. here is my code.my database columns with datatypes are also attached in a pic
Can anyone suggest me a solution? Thanks

```
 try{
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
         try (Connection conn = 
  DriverManager.getConnection(
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","hr","123"))
{ 
String qry1 = "insert into storeStaff 
values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

try {
    pstmnt=conn.prepareStatement(qry1);

    String EID=employeID.getText();
    pstmnt.setString(1,EID);

    String ename=name.getText();
    pstmnt.setString(2,ename);

    String efname=fatherName.getText();
    pstmnt.setString(3,efname);


       try{ String emcnic=cnic.getText();
    int ecnic=Integer.parseInt(emcnic);
    pstmnt.setInt(4,ecnic);}catch(Exception q)
{JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,q);}

    String edob=dob.getText();
    pstmnt.setString(5,edob);

    String adress=address.getText();
    pstmnt.setString(6,adress);

    username.setText(EID);
    pstmnt.setString(7,EID);

    String pwd=password.getText();
    pstmnt.setString(8,pwd);


    String post=facultyChoice.getItem(facultyChoice.getSelectedIndex());
    pstmnt.setString(9,post);

    pstmnt.executeQuery();
if(EID!= null && ename!=null
    && efname!=null &&edob!=null && adress!=null  && post!=null ){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Added");
}
} catch (SQLException eex) 
{JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error"+eex);}}
} catch (SQLException exx) 
{JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error"+exx);} catch 
(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error"+ex);
}}
```

Comment: Can you please add Database columns with data types in your question?

Comment: added in a pic after editing the question @sForSujit

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it

Comment: `7110332507339` - this value is too high for int data type. The limit is `2147483648`. 
You have to use BigInteger or Long data type instead of int. 
Exception is raised here  `int ecnic=Integer.parseInt(emcnic);`

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know the exact limit for int... Now i have solved the problem. t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**java.lang.NumberFormatException: ForInputString"7110332507339"**  : This is because your input value is out of range. As you are using Integer, it should be up to 2147483648. To solve this, you can use either Long, BigInteger as data types.

**java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT Parameter at Index::4** : This is because you are inserting string into column of type Date

```
 String edob=dob.getText();
    pstmnt.setString(5,edob);
```

Comment: the 2nd exception was due to the outer catch.it was pointing oout to the index 4 which is of cnic and exception was being thrown as you told that the size of int is less than my input value. not due to the date . thanks for the help..

Comment: @JAMSHAIDIQBAL Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
 try{ String emcnic=cnic.getText();
    int ecnic=Integer.parseInt(emcnic);
    pstmnt.setInt(4,ecnic);}catch(Exception q)
{JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,q);}
```

to this

```
try{ String emcnic=cnic.getText();
    long ecnic=Long.parseLong(emcnic);
    pstmnt.setLong(4,ecnic);}catch(Exception q)
{JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,q);}
```